# Fiddler: Request was retried after Receive operation failed

Tags: html, web, request, fiddler

Fiddler is giving me the note:
`This request was retried after a Receive operation failed`.

It gives me this note on all my pages, except for my homepage.

How is this error created, what does it mean and most important, is there a fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means your server failed to reuse a connection. This typically means that the server's configuration is non-optimal (or there's an interfering gateway), and the server is closing connections before they can be reused (a performance problem).

Comment: Does non-optimal means it needs to be adjusted? How do i go from here

Comment: Is it related to keep-alive timeout? I would also like to have more detailed explanation to be able to fix that.

Comment: @xmedeko -- It's not entirely possible to say. The server may close the connection at any time for any reason. *Typically* a server will close an idle connection when its keep-alive timeout expires but that timeout should be getting reset if it receives a request; there certainly could be a race condition where the request starts to send and the server closes the connection before it gets the request.

Comment: @Eric, trying to understand where the retry logic resides. If the request originally came from the browser, does the browser get some type of exception (504 or lost connection?) and then issue a retry? Another case is if I press "R" within a prior fiddler call to start a new request, would Fiddler issue a retry if that new one fails?  [New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406510)